# Mule JSON data to objects

Tags: java, json, jackson, mule

I have a json object

```
data = { 
'ad': {
    "date":"2013-06-05",
    "catagory":"6",
    "subcatagory":"5",
    "text":"John john",
    "ssn":"1306743999",
    "email":"jonbrynjar@365.is",
    "phone":"8612001"
},
'cc-info': {
    "amount": "70",
    "cardNumber": "4222222222222",
    "expiryDate": "1215",
    "currency": "ISK"
},
'dates': [
    { 'date': '2013-06-18', 'media': 1 },
    { 'date': '2013-06-19', 'media': 3 }
]
}
```

Then I have a subflow that takes the "cc-info" part of that json object and uses that data to call a third party service.
To extract the "cc-info" part of the json object I use @JsonAutoDetect class

```
@JsonAutoDetect
public class Handpoint {

private String amount;
private String cardNumber;
private String expiryDate;
private String currency;

public String getAmount() { return this.amount; }
public void setAmount(String amount) { this.amount = amount; }

public String getCardNumber() { return this.cardNumber; }
public void setCardNumber(String cardNumber) { this.cardNumber = cardNumber; }

public String getExpiryDate() { return this.expiryDate; }
public void setExpiryDate(String expireDate) { this.expiryDate = expireDate; }

public String getCurrency() { return this.currency; }
public void setCurrency(String currency) { this.currency = currency; }
}
```

When I send in the whole json object I get an error.
The question is: Do I have to put every variable in the json object into my @JsonAutoDetect class ?
Or what would be best practice for this.
I have verified that my code works when I just send in the "cc-info" part of the json objcet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need that `@JsonAutoDetect`, it doesn't do anything different from defaults without arguments.

But if your question is whether you can just ignore unknown properties, answer is yes. [Here](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHowToIgnoreUnknown) are couple of ways.

For example:

```
mapper.disable(DeserializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
```

would do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

There is an easier way to convert your JSON element to a series of objects. Have you tried the   Google **GSon** library? There is a sample:
 `import com.google.gson.Gson;`

```
         Gson gson = new Gson();
         Handpoint testing = gson.fromJson(data, Handpoint.class);

         System.out.println("Amount: " + testing.getAmount());
```

On the other hand, if you want to deserialize the dates, that contain arrays, you'd better take a look here:
[Gson Array deserialization](http://blog.patrickbaumann.com/2011/11/gson-array-deserialization/)

Comment: My paylaod is taken in here
`public ClientResponse ExtractVariablesFromPayload(@Payload JsonObject jsonObject) {
ClientResponse callHandpointRestResponse = CallHandpointRest(jsonObject.ccInfo.getCurrency(), jsonObject.ccInfo.getAmount(), jsonObject.ccInfo.getCardNumber(), jsonObject.ccInfo.getExpiryDate());
 return callHandpointRestResponse;
}`

This class here I use work with part of the json I wannt
`@JsonIgnoreProperties({"ad", "dates"})
public class JsonObject {
 @JsonProperty("cc_info")
 CcInfo ccInfo;
}`

How can I return the rest of payload, when the java class finish execution ?

Comment: @JonB dude, update your question with code, don't put code in comments it is just a mass of crap that is unreadable.